# Why am I unable to use multiple view controllers in the Apple made bouncy ball game?

Tags: swift, xcode

I created the bouncy ball game in xcode that they taught in the Apple "Develop in Swift Explorations". The game works perfectly with the viewcontroller as the initial scene but for some reason when I add another view controller and click a button to move to the game view controller scene it crashed and gives this error:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
```

This is the line of code that its giving the error on:

```
return UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController! as! ViewController
```

I didn't even write this line so I'm super confused on why I get this error. Can anyone help?

[image: xcode setup]

The game works with the game scene as the initial scene but when I add another it doesn't work.

Comment: Looking at your storyboard, they are both named "ViewController" along with your folder showing only one VC class file called "ViewController". Add a new class type ViewController to your folder name it "FirstViewController", then in storyboard click the the VC with the button and set its class to be "FirstViewController".

Comment: The line of code that crashes is assuming the first view controller is a `ViewController` using a force as! cast. If you have added another view controller first, then that won’t valid. As OneCommentMan said, it’s not clear what your new view controller is as it doesn’t seem to be part of your project. How are you moving to the game view? There is no navigation controller in the storyboard. Did you make one in code? Is the segue attached to the button a push or some other type?